# Azure B2C - Can I change the radio buttons presented on a page based on some claims values?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I want to give my users an option of the MFA authentication method that they'll be using (they can pick from phone, email, or Authenticator App). But when they log in, they should only be able to select from the methods that they've set up - so if they haven't set up an Authenticator app, for example, then that shouldn't be presented to them as an option.

I have it all running through a Custom Flow right now, and I've managed to get the page set up that presents them each of the options. But I'm not sure how I'd configure which ones are shown on the page. Is it possible to do that?

I've come up with a few possibilities so far, but as far as I can tell, I don't think any of them would work:

- I could do it from the client with custom JavaScript, but I'd need to be able to access the claims to see which authentication methods have been set up. I've tried Googling that but haven't come up with much for it.
- I also took a look at having my Enumeration options having a condition, but as far as I can tell there's no support for that.
- A third option I've come up with is to have different profiles which I'll run, which are conditional on the MFAs they have set up. So if they have only phone, I show a profile specific to phone authentication. If it's Phone and Email, I can show a page with those two options. Etc. for each of the possibilities (just email, just auth app, email & auth app, phone & auth app, and all three). But that's a lot more messy so I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

This sample provides a screen option where you can present the user with the choice (phone or email in the sample).  I've used it and it works, but these options have to be presented in a self-asserted page apart from the profiles where you actually execute one of them.   [MFA Email or Phone](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone)